# C string manipulation: split text into multiple lines

Tags: c, arduino

To provide context, this question is about an Arduino project where I have an OLED display screen (256x64) and I want to split a paragraph of text into multiple lines (i.e. "left aligned") to fit on the OLED.

I will do this from my own function call, and my question here is about how to write this function. There are many ways to skin this cat, but I'm looking for the most sensible and elegant way.

I'm using the u8g graphics library, which has a function that returns the width of a string for a given font. It can also return the height of a font. There's no reason, then, to pass line height into my function, only the starting x and y position, the text, and the x-position at which to wrap the text.

**Question 1: is this sensible?**

```
void drawMultiLine (char* text, byte startx, byte starty, byte endx)
```

I'm not considering pagination or scrolling, so there's no need for an "endy" variable.

**Question 2: how would you write this function?**

Can you provide a top-level description of the most efficient way to do this?

I am not concerned about the case where a word is too long to fit on one line. It can either break the line anyway with no hyphen, or simply not wrap the word (ie extend beyond the bounds).

For example, I have tried this, but gave-up because it seemed too convoluted:

- loop through each character of the `text[]` array, and assign each char to the equivalent array index of a buffer `buff[]`
- null terminate the buff for each iteration of this loop, in order that we can use `u8g.getStrWidth`to return the width of the string so far
- stop looping when `u8g.getStrWidth(buff) > endx - startx`
- now the text in char array `buff` would fit within the width of the display if we printed it, however we want to wrap words, so trace backwards from the end of buff[] array to find the first ASCII space
- add the null termination character at the array index of this space
- continue somehow from the first character of the word we stopped at, and loop all the above until we have as many lines as the paragraph of text requires

The above uses three intermediate variables to track indices, three loops, and I think it's generally inelegant.

Comment: Your last step should be "move down a line and to the left edge of the screen," since you're essentially "inserting" a newline at the wrap point.

Comment: How would you like to handle the case where one word is too large to fit the width?

Comment: I'm a bit out of context, but can you do it by printing each char one at a time? You set a var `curX = startx` and one `curY = starty`, then starting at `i=0` you print `text[i]` at `curX`, `curY`, add to `curX` the width of the char `text[i]`, if `curX > endx` set `curX = startx` and add to `curY` the line height (or the max of the chars heights since last reset of `curX`). Repeat untill end of `text`. This may crop the last char on each line, do the last step before printing, to avoid this.

Comment: @MargaretBloom If I understand correctly, this would split lines in the middle of words, which I don't want

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood _It can either break the line anyway with no hyphen, or simply not wrap the word_. It's trivial to adapt the algorithm anyway. [here](http://pastebin.com/jcdKbxxa) a very simple C code, It is not coded nor thought-out well enough to be an answer but it can be a starting point.

Comment: Hi @MargaretBloom, it's an excellent starting point, thank you. You should have written that as a proper answer, I'd mark it as "answered" then!